# How to fix floating point errors in OpenGL PBR

Tags: opengl, pbr

After finishing my PBR implementation I noticed that when I get close to a reflective surface, artifacts appear which I think are floating point errors.
I would really wish not to using doubles as my GPU tends to handle doubles in a performance heavy way
[image: Far]

[image: Closer]

[image: Really close]

Here's my PBR IBL code (All the environment maps are correct as well as the deferred buffers):

```
// Deferred rendering
vec2 texcoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / textureSize(R_GBP, 0);
vec3  P = texture2D(R_GBP, texcoord).xyz;
vec4  A = texture2D(R_GBA, texcoord).rgba;
vec3  N = texture2D(R_GBN, texcoord).xyz;
float M = texture2D(R_GBM, texcoord).r;
float R = texture2D(R_GBR, texcoord).r;

vec3 V = normalize(R_CameraPos - P);
vec3 T = reflect(-V, N);
vec3 F0 = mix(vec3(0.04), A.rgb, M);

float NDV = max(dot(N, V), 0);
vec3 kS = FresnelSchlickRoughness(NDV, F0, R); 
vec3 kD = (1 - kS) * (1 - M);
vec3 irr = textureCube(R_EnvironmentIrradiance, N).rgb;
vec3 dfs = irr * A.rgb;

const float MaxReflectionLod = 4;
vec3 preF_col = textureLod(R_EnvironmentPreFilter, T, R * MaxReflectionLod).rgb;   
vec2 brdf = texture2D(R_EnvironmentBRDF, vec2(NDV, R)).rg;
vec3 specular = preF_col * (kS * brdf.x + brdf.y);

vec3 ambient = kD * dfs + specular;
```

Comment: Looks like you store your normals with too low precision. Have a look at [this paper](http://jcgt.org/published/0003/02/01/paper.pdf) for an overview of possible better encodings. Also, storing the 3D position in a texture is a total waste of ressources, all you need is the Z Buffer, the rest can be reconstructed in the shader.

Comment: @derhass I just found out that I set my position buffer to 16bit precision. This was after I took your advice on using the depth buffer for position.

Comment: you could also sample 4 neighbours in checkerboard fashion and try to 'smooth' within a certain tolerance, but that obviously also will give other artifacts.

Comment: (the sampling would be on the normal values obviously, maybe that was not entirely clear in my previous comment) but @derhass is right about the representation of the normals - if you need to retain more precision in the dot product, you probably have to break it up in parts.